# How can I make variables in a Shiny app acccessible to external R scripts deployed with the app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am relatively new to programming/R/Shiny. I have a network of R scripts that take in data, transform it, and produce figures that are output to a PDF. I have been using this for some time now. I now need to transfer that process to a Shiny app.

This has been problematic because none of the variables that are present in one script can be used in another.

Is there a "simple" way to make these variables accessible between R scripts ? That would be a much, much simpler solution than trying to transfer the entirety of the code into the app.r file. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Example code - Here, I would like the user to upload a CSV file and then press a button that runs an R script that modifies and adds to the data, creating two new dataframes. Those two dataframes would then be used in "report.R" to create PDF reports.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('upload', 'Choose file to upload',
            accept ='.csv'
            ),
  actionButton('analyze', 'Analyze the data')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    read.csv <- vroom(input$file$datapath)
  })
  observeEvent(input$analyze, {
    source("analyze.R")
    #this transforms data from the csv and produces new dataframes based on the original, call them df1 and df2. df1 and df2 are then used as data in reports generated by:
    source("report.R")
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but wouldn't it work if you pass `local = TRUE` to your `source` calls? That's still kind of hacky though, it would probably be better if you refactor the logic in those files as functions.

Comment: I see that you deleted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226540/how-can-i-remove-sublist-values-that-are-duplicates-in-different-order-in-r/69226586#69226586) when you got an answer.  It is a very bad practise because the next time you post a question, people will not tempt to answer it.  It is just that when somebody post a question, others also spend their valuable time to help.